# Getting a Classification Tree to "Branch Out"

Tags: r

I'm trying to develop a Classification Tree for a project I'm working on.  It involves attempts to classify individuals based on a set of characteristics into different levels of "donor-types".  While I have technically gotten R to generate a tree, it is a Single-Node Tree that succeeds at only determining the classification of one "donor-type".

My questions is this:  is there any way I can force R to develop other branches?
I've included the code below.

```
library(tree)

hrc.memclass <- read.csv("hrc_memclass.csv", header = TRUE) 
hrc.memclass <- na.omit(hrc.memclass)  
hrc.memdat <- hrc.memclass[,-1]

tree.memdat <- tree(MEMBER.TYPE ~ ., data = hrc.memdat)  
summary(tree.memdat) 

plot(tree.memdat) 
text(tree.memdat, pretty = 0)  

tree.memdat
```

Comment: Without access to your data it will be hard to help. Can you post the CSV online somewhere for others to access?

Comment: @Mark, I could email it to you, or I could upload a copy to Google Sheets and share it with you.